# How do I set a range of fields as the value in a python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

My input file looks like this:

```
1_10001 1       10001   1       342     0       0       0       342
1_10002 1       10002   3       426     379     34      0       13
1_10003 1       10003   2       506     480     0       0       26
1_10004 1       10004   1       562     0       562     0       0
```

I want to create a dictionary where the first field (1_10001 etc) is the key, and 2:8 are the value. I tried this:

```
d = {}
with open("test.in") as f:
     for line in f:
             sep = line.split()
             d[sep[1]] = sep[2:]
```

It doesn't throw and error, but d looks like this:

> > > d
> > >       {'1': ['10010', '1', '634', '0', '634', '0', '0']}

I want the key to be the string "1_10001" etc, not '1'. Also, where is the rest of it? I also tried putting 2:8 in a list, but that gave the error:

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

I am completely new to python, so please forgive any sillyness. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Lists in Python are indexed from 0.

Try:

```
d = {}
with open("test.in") as f:
     for line in f:
             sep = line.split()
             d[sep[0]] = sep[1:]
```